# Laravel Socialite Github - error 401 Unauthorized/Bad credentials

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I've got fresh installation of Laravel 9 with Socialite package. This is my `config/services.php` file:

```
'github' => [
    'client_id' => 'xxx',
    'client_secret' => 'xxx',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:3000/login',
],
```

From my frontend Nuxt application, I redirect to github oauth page `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx` which works fine. I confirm authorization for my account and then it redirects me back to my frontend `http://localhost:3000/login` as this URL is set in my GitHub settings for Authorization callback URL.

In return URL I have my code for authorization: `http://localhost:3000?code=xxx`

Then I do axios call to my Laravel server:

```
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: 'http://localhost/api/auth/socialite/github',
    data: qs.stringify({
        client_id: 'xxx',
        client_secret: 'xxx',
        code: this.$route.query.code,
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
        response_type: 'code'
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
})
```

On server side, in `routes/api.php` I have this route:

```
Route::post("auth/socialite/{provider}", function($provider){
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
});
```

And when I'm trying to return user from github using Socialite, it returns this error:

```
Client error: `GET https://api.github.com/user` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}
```

So Socialite calls this URL `https://api.github.com/user` with my credentials and is trying to get user from github if I understand it right. But somehow it returns the error. I have checked my `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect` URL...

I'm sure everything works fine until I call `Socialite::driver`..., because If I kill the process with for example `dd($provider)` before `Socialite::driver`... it returns `"github"` as it should. And If I kill the process and take generated code parameter from github page and I'm trying to do the same call on Postman with my credentials, Github returns me token.

So I would expect for Socialite call to do the same.

I have two questions:

1. Is my structure of code (communication of frontend with backend and back, usage of Socialite package...) right?
2. Why it is showing me error when the same call in Postman works?